# Persistent WITH statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, with-statement

How can i keep in memory a table created by `WITH` statement until the end of script?

Example:

```
;WITH Group AS
(
    SELECT Name, LastName, Age FROM dbo.persons WHERE Age BETWEEN 25 AND 30
)
--Group table stays in memory until the following query
SELECT * FROM Group

--Group does not exist here.
SELECT * FROM Group WHERE AGE = 27
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i want to know if it's possible by using `WITH` statement.

Comment: It is definitely not possible when using a common table expression (CTE).  You should use a temp table or table variable depending on how many records will be in it.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg, any specific reason you are not making that an answer?

Comment: NO, it's not possible.